# Applications of Cohen reals (obtained by forcing) and maths without Continuum Hypothesis?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, real-numbers, cardinals, forcing

At it is well know, the von Neumann universe (or von Neumann hierarchy of sets) $V$ is a class of hereditary well-founded sets which can be used as a model for Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory (ZFC). This was stuff from the 1930s. Then in the 1960s, Paul Cohen invented the technique of forcing, and constructing a forcing extension $V[G]$ of $V$ using some Countable Chanin Condition forcing $P$. Then in the new universe $V[G]$, we have exotic new sets satisfying the exioms of ZFC.

In particular, in $V[G]$ we can "force" the existence of a set of reals $\mathbb{R}$ which does not satisfy the Continuum Hypothesis. In the original construction of Cohen, back to 1966, the set $\mathbb{R}$ in $V[G]$ has cardinal $\aleph_2$ (instead the usual assumption that $\text{card}(\mathbb{R}) = \aleph_1$). Then in the "forced universe" $V[G]$, the continuum hypothesis no longer holds, because between the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$, which have cardinal $\aleph_0$ and the whole set of reals, which now has cardinal $\aleph_2$ is possible to find sets $A$, with $\text{card}(\mathbb{Q}) < \text{card}(A) < \text{card}(\mathbb{R})$.

I wonder if someone have developed any application of Cohen reals, for which $\text{card}(\mathbb{R}) = \aleph_2$, other than model theory, or the foundations of set theory. For example, what about integration, measeure theory, real analysis or topology?

Comment: Real analysis is usually constructed with reference to only the ordered field axioms and the least upper bound property, so it does not really matter what the cardinality of the reals is. I did however see somewhere a construction of a non-measureable set assuming CH, so there might be something...